# Standard C++ equivalent to a CTypedPtrList

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

I'm porting Windows code to Linux and I'm new to C++. Is there a standard C++ library equivalent to [`CTypedPtrList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/850101a7.aspx)?

It's currently used in the code to contain some of our classes like so:

`CTypedPtrList<CPtrList, OurClass*> variable_name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exact equivalent, but your best bet is [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: `std::list<OurClass*>`, to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks. `list` and `vector` seemed to be the obvious choices, I just wasn't sure if there was some other subtle difference that I wasn't aware of. Cheers.